# Setting Internal Read Write properties for an existing file

Tags: android, air, native, internal

I'm having an issue with opening internal data files in native applications

Its properly important to point out that I'm fairly new to Android development but not new to programming

Setup

I have a mobile Air application which i am running on an Android device. To load PDF's/ play videos within the application I have written a native extension to load the files via their native application.

Problem

When testing the app i found that file's stored in the external storage were loading fine and files in the internal storage were presenting messages from the native applications  like cannot play file or cannot open file.( files in internal storage are downloaded and saved on the Air application end ).

This lead me to think its the permission setup within Android.

I know that files within the internal storage are private by default

I have read how to write to a file setting its permission using openFileOutput
but as the file already exists this won't work. I could load the file in and spit it out again but this isn't ideal as will result in what might be unnecessary overhead.

I'm not sure how to proceed, do i need to set a manifest properties on the Air App side? Android App side? both sides? If so which one and where

Or is their a way to change it at run-time, i found the setReadable function but its at API level 9 and i am idealy aiming a little lower than that.

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
public static void openFile( Activity parentActivity, String filePath, String fileType, String mimeType ) {

    //Create the file we are to create 
    File fileToOpen = new File(filePath);

    //Check if the file exists 
    if( fileToOpen.exists() ) {

        //The path of the file we want to open
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(fileToOpen);

        //Create a new intent of the file we want to view
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        //Set the path and the mime type  for the file 
        intent.setDataAndType(path, mimeType);

        //Remove any other activities 
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        //Check that its within the try and catch block
        try {


            //Open the file by stating a new activity 
            parentActivity.startActivity(intent);            
        } 
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

            //Make a pop-up informing that we don't have an application to open the file
            Toast.makeText( parentActivity,"No Application Available to View " + fileType,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } else {

        //Display an alert which will show that the file dosn't exist
        Toast.makeText( parentActivity, fileType+" file dosn't exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
    }
}
```